# How to validate custom ASP.NET MVC helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, helper

I need to get working validation of the custom ASP.NET MVC helper.

**Helper**

```
public static class AutocompleteHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string actionUrl)
    {
        return CreateAutocomplete(helper, expression, actionUrl, null, null);
    }
    public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string actionUrl, bool? isRequired, string placeholder)
    {

        return CreateAutocomplete(helper, expression, actionUrl, placeholder, isRequired);
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString CreateAutocomplete<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string actionUrl, string placeholder, bool? isRequired)
    {
        var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
                             {
                                 { "data-autocomplete", true },
                                 { "data-action", actionUrl }
                             };

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(placeholder))
        {
            attributes.Add("placeholder", placeholder);
        }

        if (isRequired.HasValue && isRequired.Value)
        {
            attributes.Add("required", "required");
        }

        attributes.Add("class", "form-control formControlAutocomplete");


        attributes.Add("maxlength", "45");


        Func<TModel, TValue> method = expression.Compile();
        var value = method((TModel)helper.ViewData.Model);
        var baseProperty = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
        var hidden = helper.Hidden(baseProperty, value);

        attributes.Add("data-value-name", baseProperty);

        var automcompleteName = baseProperty + "_autocomplete";
        var textBox = helper.TextBox(automcompleteName, null, string.Empty, attributes);

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine(hidden.ToHtmlString());
        builder.AppendLine(textBox.ToHtmlString());

        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
@Html.AutocompleteFor(x => x.ProductUID, Url.Action("AutocompleteProducts", "Requisition"), true, "Start typing Product name...")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ProductUID)
```

I seems like validating but no message appears.
[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of your text field is `ProductUID_autocomplete` but your `ValidationMessageFor` which is supposed to display the error message is bound to `ProductUID`.

So make sure that you are binding your error message to the same property:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("ProductUID_autocomplete")
```

It appears that whatever custom logic you might have to validate this field is injecting the error under the `ProductUID_autocomplete` key in the `ModelState`.

This being said, why not just invoke the `ValidationMessage` helper inside your custom helper? This way you will have less things to type in your view and the *logic* with those names being suffixed with `_autocomplete` will stay inside the helper only.

Comment: Thank you very much Darin! You always help! God bless you, man!